# Why did the Gnurrs come from the Voodverk Out?

Tags: music, papa-schimmelhorn

Please identify the name of the main character and how the brought the Gnurrs from the Voodverk out and with what instrument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this after a quick [Google search](http://www.fictionwise.com/ebooks/b65317/The-Gnurrs-Come-from-the-Voodvork-Out/Reginald-Bretnor/?si=0)

The main character is  Papa Schimmelhorn and his instrument is a bassoon, he calls it a "gnurr-pfeife"

Comment: And the gnurrs came from the voodverk out!

Comment: A fine yarn, that.